# Splitting strings into lists and splitting again

Tags: python, list

I want to split the string

```
"   510     -9999999  9             99         12             5             [3, 0]        []            [6]       "
```

(which contains more or less random numbers of whitespaces between the entries) into it's component parts, including the lists within the string. I can get to this

```
['510', '-9999999', '9', '99', '12', '5', '[3,', '0]', '[]', '[6]']
```

through using split and replace. However, I then want to reconstitute the lists within the original string so that I can get to

```
['510', '-9999999', '9', '99', '12', '5', '[3,0]', '[]', '[6]'].
```

The real problem is that this string is one of many and the lists may contain many, or no components so I have to deal with this is a general way.

I could potentially search for `'['`, then search for `']'` to close up the list but, as I don't know the length of any of the lists going in, this seems an inefficient way of doing things.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please consult [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I believe it will help.

Comment: Can those lists be nested?

Comment: paging @Paul McGuire for the pyparsing solution ..

Comment: Just jam in some commas and use `eval`.  Disclaimer: Don't do this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always regex, but you can do it on the cheap like this

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split(s.replace('[','"[').replace(']',']"'))
['510', '-9999999', '9', '99', '12', '5', '[3, 0]', '[]', '[6]']
```

The proper solution would be to use `pyparsing` module, or even better to control the input source to give you something more sensible like json.

Comment: This works great, thanks! I'm new to Python and still trying to get to grips with the import/export of messy datasets.

Answer (score 0):

If lists can't be nested then I think it is possible to preprocess string with:

```
s = "   510     -9999999  9             99         12             5             [3, 0]        []            [6]       "

opened = False
s_new = ""
for i in s:
    if i == "[":
        opened = True
    if i == "]":
        opened = False
    if not opened or (opened and i != " "):
        s_new += i
```

And then split it into list:

```
l = s_new.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

If lists aren't nested, you can try this:

```
def mysplit (a):
    return re.split(' +', re.sub('\\[(.*?)\\]', lambda m: '[{}]'.format(m.groups()[0].replace(' ', '')), a))
```